# Statement and PreparedStatement

Tags: java

Здравствуйте объясните пожалуйста разница между `Statement` и `PreparedStatement` в каком случае нужно использовать `Statment` и в каком случае `PreparedStatment`
если не сложно чуть подробнее объясните.Спасибо

Comment: Если в запрос нужно передавать параметры, используете `PreparedStatement`. Если не нужно, используете `Statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выдержка:

> PreparedStatement прекомпилирован, исполнение может происходить
>   несколько быстрее, чем в объектах Statement. В результате
>   SQL-выражения, которые исполняются часто, в целях улучшения
>   производительности создают в виде объектов PreparedStatement.

Подробнее можно почитать вот тут - http://www.javaportal.ru/java/tutorial/tutorialJDBC/preparedstatement.html
Кроме этого, есть и официальная документация, там тоже можно (и нужно) смотреть (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)